# Making ul li dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu, now trying to use it as a filter. pass a value when I click the menu item start filtering But I am a bit confused at Jquery part. How to pass "name" & "value" and start filtering. And the important issue is when I click one item and filter. After that when I click next item, I don't want it to start over. I want to keep old history of search. and add it to new filter.

```js
 var allOptions = $(".init").children('li');
  $("ul").on("click", function() {
      allOptions.removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
      allOptions.slideUp();
  });
```

```css
#filter-wrapper
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#filter-wrapper ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#filter-wrapper ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#filter-wrapper ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id="filter-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Cheapest Cars</a></li>
    <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Newest Cars</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Car Color</a>
      <ul class="init" name="sortbycolor">
        <li data-value="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
        <li data-value="black"><a href="#">Black</a></li>
        <li data-value="silver"><a href="#">Silver</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For example, when I select Red then Car Color changed with the Red.

P.S: And by the way the `name=""` that I gave, it comes from Laravel controller. It contains the data.

And this is the old filter of mine. It's working with this. I can filter the data.

```
   <form>
     <select name="sortbyprice" class="custom-select custom-select-md" style="width: 100px;">
       <option value="asc">cheapest</option>
       <option value="desc">Expensive</option>
     </select>
     <select id="cars" name="cars" class="custom-select custom-select-md" style="width: 100px;">
      <option value="" disabled selected>car colors</option>
      <option value="red">red</option>
      <option value="blue">blue</option>
      <option value="black">black</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success" id="filter-btn">Filter</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You need to use `<select><option></option></select>` to submit data, not `<ul>.`

Comment: here I don't want to use select and option. instead of that I am trying to use `ul` `li` with jQuery.

Comment: So you want to submit data by ajax?

Comment: Multiple errors here. First data-value"red" etc...missing "=" signs...data-value = "red"...second .data is not a function..

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the 'data-value' attribute on click?

Comment: choosing value onclick. and filter the data by submit. because I have more then one dropdown. So I try to select more then one value at once and search. @MerakMarey of course if it possible, I want to search directly on click, but that time. next search is start over... I want to keep the old filter data when I click the next filter...

Comment: I updated the explanation in the question. please check it out. @MerakMarey

Comment: Please also update the code with the corrections I pointed on the comment.

Comment: Still the errors on the html..on the li's .. data-value = "red"...missing the equal signs

Comment: sorry about that, that's my typo. @MerakMarey

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187090/discussion-between-wow-me-and-merak-marey).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is what you want, but you can try the code below and tell me what you think

```js
var mockData = [
    {
        make: 'a',
        color: 'red',
        price: 1000
    },
    {
        make: 'a',
        color: 'black',
        price: 2000
    },
    {
        make: 'b',
        color: 'red',
        price: 1
    },
    {
        make: 'a',
        color: 'silver',
        price: 3000
    },
    {
        make: 'c',
        color: 'black',
        price: 1500
    },
    {
        make: 'a',
        color: 'red',
        price: 1500
    }
];

var allOptions = $('.init').children('li');
// use an object to store the filter options selected by the user
// you can then use the information in this object to do the filtering
// by sending an AJAX request or just filter the already fetched data
var filterOptions = {
    sortbycolor: '',
    sortbymake: '',
    sortbyprice: ''
};

$(allOptions).on('click', function () {
    // get the items' data-value
    var value = $(this)[0].dataset.value;
    // select the corresponding <a> tag
    var button = $(this).parent()[0].previousElementSibling;
    // get the corresponding name attribute, e.g. sortbycolor
    var type = $($(this).parent()[0]).attr('name');

    // set the filterOptions
    filterOptions[type] = value;

    // change the displayed text of the filter when the user select something
    $(button).text(function (idx, content) {
        // here I choose using a colon ':' as the separator,
        // you can use whatever you want
        var colonIndex = content.indexOf(':');
        // example for baseContent is 'Car Color'
        var baseContent = content;

        if (colonIndex > -1) {
            baseContent = content.slice(0, colonIndex);
        }

        // e.g 'Car Color: red
        return baseContent + ': ' + value;
    });

    allOptions.slideUp();
    console.log('update filterOptions: ', filterOptions);

    // filter the already fetched data
    var filteredData = mockData.filter(function (val) {
        var isValid = true;

        if (isValid && filterOptions.sortbycolor) {
            isValid = val.color === filterOptions.sortbycolor;
        }

        if (isValid && filterOptions.sortbymake) {
            isValid = val.make === filterOptions.sortbymake;
        }

        return isValid;
    });

    // sort the data by price
    // hard-code the sorting direction here for simplicity,
    // you can set this dynamically with the onclick event
    filterOptions.sortbyprice = 'asc';

    if (filterOptions.sortbyprice === 'asc') {
        filteredData.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.price - b.price;
        });
    } else if (filterOptions.sortbyprice === 'desc') {
        filteredData.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.price - a.price;
        });
    }

    console.log('filteredData: ', filteredData);

    // or you can send an ajax request to the server,
    // and let the server handle the filtering for you
    
    // you have to set the keys and values inside
    // the 'data' youself, below is just an example
    // as I don't know what your server's API looks like
    $.get({
        url: 'url-to-your-server',
        data: {
            color: filterOptions.sortbycolor,
            make: filterOptions.sortbymake
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // do something with the response,
            // maybe it contains the filtered result
            // however, I am not sure how does your API look like
        }
    });
});

// to deal with the left over css style(display: none) introduced by .slideUp()
$('.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function () {
    allOptions.css('display', 'block');
});

console.log('initial filterOptions: ', filterOptions);
```

```css
#filter-wrapper {
    margin-top: 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#filter-wrapper ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul li.current-menu-item {
    background: #ddd
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 200px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Cheapest Cars</a></li>
        <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Newest Cars</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="car-color">Car Color</a>
            <ul class="init" name="sortbycolor">
                <li data-value="red"><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                <li data-value="black"><a href="#">Black</a></li>
                <li data-value="silver"><a href="#">Silver</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="make">Make</a>
            <ul class="init" name="sortbymake">
                <li data-value="a"><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li data-value="b"><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li data-value="c"><a href="#">C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your afford, nearly what I want. Actually dropdown is working. But filtering is not working. I don't know why. When I pass the names and pass the values but when I click it, it's not filtering. Actually, I updated the code above with my old selectBox. could you please check it out?

Comment: and one more  thing, when I try to filter not by Ajax(because it's not working) but by links, it's not keeping the first filter history. next click is start over... For example, I filter price, after that I filter color. It's forgeting sortbyprice... etc.

Comment: If the links in the `<a>` tag you use in your actual code is not a '#' sign, but an actual link to another page, then the `filterOptions` object might be overwritten by the initial state or lost due to the page refresh. One approach for keeping the `filterOptions` is to use the browser's `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. Another approach is to prevent the page refresh when the user clicks the dropdown menu item.

Comment: Maybe you could post your filtering logic to the question, so that we can have more information about how it works.

Comment: Actually, i don't gave links/urls first. `<a>` tag just contained "#" but still when I click the li, it doesn't filters... I posted in the question my early selectBox. you could check it out. for example In DB I have "cars" column. every row has a item like "red", "blue" so I am fetching those rows with the column. In Laravel Controller. Name is Column name="cars" and value is item in the rows... it worked with the selectBox... But I don't want to use selectBox trying to do it with `ul` `li`...

Comment: sorry for the burden, how can I insert ajax request in this function? which part?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am not familiar with the Laravel framework, I guess in your old style selectBox, you perform the filtering action when the user clicks the submit button, and wait for the server response with the filtered data? The the `ul li` version, you can either add a submit button, which works the same way as the old selectBox. Or you can add an ajax call inside the onClick function, for example, just before the line `console.log('update filterOptions: ', filterOptions);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187163/discussion-between-wow-me-and-ray-chan).

Comment: could you insert an example for the ajax request?

Comment: @Wowme Updated the answer, however, I don't know how does your backend API look like, so it's hard for me to help.

Comment: hello, can I invite you to this question. Questions are similar and I trying to use your code to fix the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319033/is-it-possible-to-filter-already-fetched-data-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I eliminated your css, you are just interested in the color value - correct ?

```
<div id="filter-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Cheapest Cars</a></li>
        <li name="sortbyprice" class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Newest Cars</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Car Color</a>
            <ul class="init" name="sortbycolor">
                <li><a href="#" data-value="red">Red</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="black">Black</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="silver">Silver</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    var allOptions = $(".init").children('li');

    // I think you are only interested in the html content of the a (anchor)

    $("li[data-value] > a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        allOptions.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        let filterVal = $(this).data('value'); // do something with this ...
        let li = $('<li />').html( filterVal);
        $("ul.init").html('').append( li); // ul.init just has the value of the filter

        // allOptions.slideUp(); // superfluos
    });
</script>
```