# Is it possible to filter already fetched data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the Laravel framework and fetching data. Now I am trying to filter the data with Ajax and jQuery. But a couple problem that I am facing...

### UPDATED 4

When I start filter, there is this error looping:

> "/var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>       "line": 255,
>       "trace": [
>           {
>               "file": "/var/www/html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
>               "line": 242,
>               "function": "methodNotAllowed",
>               "class": "Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection",
>               "type": "->"
>           },

is there that I am missing something about the controller? or routing? Thank you for help!

Laravel Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
  $q = $request->q;
  $sortbyprice = $request->sortbyprice;
  $region = $request->region;
  $rooms = $request->rooms;
  $price = $request->price;
  $max = $request->input('max');
  $min = $request->input('min');

  $paginationData = [
      'q' => $q
  ];

  $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
      ->where('lat', '!=', '')
      ->where('lng', '!=', '')
      ->where('price', '!=', '')
      ->when($q, function($query, $q) use ($paginationData) {
          $paginationData['q'] = $q;
          return $query->where(function($query) use ($q) {
                      $query->where("building_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                          ->orWhere("address", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                          ->orWhere("company_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                          ->orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                          ->orWhere("rooms", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%");
                  });
      })
      ->when($sortbyprice, function($query, $order) use ($paginationData) {
          if(!in_array($order, ['asc','desc'])) {
              $order = 'asc';
          }
          $paginationData['sortbyprice'] = $order;
          return $query->orderBy('price', $order);

      }, function($query) {
          return $query->orderBy('price');
      })
      ->when($region, function($query, $regionId) use ($paginationData) {
          $paginationData['region'] = $regionId;
          return $query->where('region', $regionId);
      })
      ->when($rooms, function($query, $roomsId) use ($paginationData) {
          $paginationData['rooms'] = $roomsId;
          return $query->where('rooms', "LIKE", "%" . $roomsId . "%");
      })
      ->when($max, function($query, $max) use ($min, $paginationData) {
          $paginationData['min'] = $min;
          $paginationData['max'] = $max;
          return $query->whereBetween('price', [$min, $max]);
      })
      // ->toSql()
      ->paginate(100);

  $paginationData = array_filter($paginationData);

  return view("home", compact('estates', 'q','paginationData'));
}
```

```js
var displayList = $('#display-wrapper ol');
var selectedOptions = {
    sortbyprice: '',
    rooms: '',
    region: ''
};


$('html').click(function () {
    console.log(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.region').on('click', function () {

    var selectValue = $(this).data('value');

    $('#region').text(selectValue);
    selectedOptions.region = selectValue;
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.rooms').on('click', function () {
    var selectValue = $(this).data('value');

    $('#rooms').text(selectValue);
    selectedOptions.rooms = selectValue;
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.sortbyprice').on('click', function () {
    var selectValue = $(this).text();

    selectedOptions.sortbyprice = selectValue;
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

function serialize(options) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var key in options) {
        arr.push(key + '=' + options[key]);
    }

    return encodeURI(arr.join('&'));
}

function fetchDataFromServer(options) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home',
        data: serialize(options),
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                console.error(response.error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
               
                updateDisplay(displayList);
            }
        },
        error: function (html, status) {
            console.log(html.responseText);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}

function updateDisplay(node, data) {
    var template = data.reduce(function (acc, item) {
        return acc + '<li><p>Region: ' + item.region + '</p><p>Price: ' + item.price + '</p><p>Rooms: ' + item.rooms + '</p></li>';
    }, '');

    node.empty();
    node.append(template);
}
```

```css
#filter-wrapper {
    margin-top: 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#filter-wrapper ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul li.current-menu-item {
    background: lightblue;
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 200px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-wrapper">
              <ul>
                  <li><a class="sortbyprice" href="javascript:" data-value="sortbyprice">Cheapest</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" id="rooms">間取り</a>
                      <ul class="init" name="rooms">
                          <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="1DK">1DK</a></li>
                          <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="2LDK">2LDK</a></li>
                          <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="3LDK">3LDK</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" id="region">エリア</a>
                      <ul class="init" name="region">
                          <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="関西">関西</a></li>
                          <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="関東">関東</a></li>
                          <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="北海道">北海道</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>

          <div id="display-wrapper">
              <ol></ol>
          </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes it is possible but I suggest you use `pagination` and then create a filter where it fetch data from the database again based on your parameters.

Comment: yes , By use of data-table you can done this. Please see this link https://datatables.net/.

Comment: Are you getting any response inside the $.ajax success callback? And for the "I mean not start over every click" part, do you mean if there are two dropdowns, when the user selects an option in the first dropdown, you want to initiate an ajax request with the options from the first dropdown. After that, when the user selects the options in the second dropdown, you need to send an ajax request with both the option from the 1st dropdown and the option from the 2nd dropdown?

Comment: I updated the code and write down my response too... And you are right. For example, I click 2LDK and filter and then I click region, Tokyo and filter it too... But try to not start over the for second click add the result to first filter. I am kind of update... @RayChan Also, I have three input in the html but in the ajax I can just add region, How can I add all of those into Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to create a variable to store all the options selected by the user, and on each ajax request, you send the corresponding data to the server in order to get the filtered result.

I removed the hidden HTML form, and choose to use an object instead.

The ajax request in this code snippet is not working because there is no end-point '/home' for me to get the resources, but I think this will work on your machine.

As a side note, the id attribute should be unique, or else, the behavior might not be what you'd expected. And for the onclick handlers, if you have a lot of dropdowns, you should consider generating them with a loop instead of copy and pasting like I did, but for demo purposes, I will leave it as it is for now.

```js
// a sample display
var displayList = $('#display-wrapper ol');
// create an object to store the selected options
var selectedOptions = {
    sortbyprice: '',
    rooms: '',
    region: ''
};

// this event handler is for logging out the selectedOptions
// so that you can see what happens to the variable
// you should remove this in production
$('html').click(function () {
    console.log(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.region').on('click', function () {
    // I guess what you're trying to do here is to update the dropdown
    // text into the selected value, e.g replace エリア with 関西
    var selectValue = $(this).data('value');

    $('#region').text(selectValue);
    selectedOptions.region = selectValue;
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.rooms').on('click', function () {
    var selectValue = $(this).data('value');

    $('#rooms').text(selectValue);
    selectedOptions.rooms = selectValue;
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

$('a.sortbyprice').on('click', function () {
    // var selectValue = $(this).text();
    // selectedOptions.sortbyprice = selectValue;
    selectedOptions.sortbyprice = 'asc';
    fetchDataFromServer(selectedOptions);
});

function fetchDataFromServer(options) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/home',
        data: options,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                // sweetAlert("Oops...", response.data, "error");
                console.error(response.error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
                // I assume the data structure of the response is something like
                // var reponse = {
                //     data: [
                //         {
                //             price: 123,
                //             rooms: '1DK',
                //             region: '関西'
                //         },
                //         ......
                //     ]
                // }
                // This is an example function for updating the UI
                // You can replace this function according to your needs
                updateDisplay(displayList, response.data);
            }
        },
        error: function (html, status) {
            console.log(html.responseText);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
}

function updateDisplay(node, data) {
    // build the html for the node(<ol> tag)
    var template = data.reduce(function (acc, item) {
        return acc + '<li><p>Region: ' + item.region + '</p><p>Price: ' + item.price + '</p><p>Rooms: ' + item.rooms + '</p></li>';
    }, '');

    // add the template to the node(<ol> tag)
    node.empty();
    node.append(template);
}
```

```css
#filter-wrapper {
    margin-top: 15px
}

/*
 *  I added this line for demo purpose
 *  Not sure whether you'll need this in your app
 *  Feel free to remove this
 */
#filter-wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

#filter-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#filter-wrapper ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul li.current-menu-item {
    background: lightblue;
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 200px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px
}

#filter-wrapper ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}

#filter-wrapper ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="sortbyprice" href="javascript:" data-value="sortbyprice">Cheapest</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="rooms">間取り</a>
            <ul class="init" name="rooms">
                <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="1DK">1DK</a></li>
                <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="2LDK">2LDK</a></li>
                <li><a class="rooms" href="javascript:" data-value="3LDK">3LDK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="region">エリア</a>
            <ul class="init" name="region">
                <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="関西">関西</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="関東">関東</a></li>
                <li><a class="region" href="javascript:" data-value="北海道">北海道</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="display-wrapper">
    <ol></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Really, thank you for the afford. when I delete comment from data part, then select li stop being selected. So I can't start filter, I updated the code, could you please check it out. Do I missing something.

Comment: I edited the question to fix the syntax error, the mockResponse is just for demo purpose, you should remove it in production. You can try again and see if it's working now.

Comment: oh! thank you for editing and help. Now I am getting the same error looping in the console as before. I update the code. By the way sorry for the burden. :)

Comment: I am not so familiar with laravel, but I guess your backend is expecting a 'GET' method instead of 'POST' method, maybe you can try using `$.ajax({ type: 'GET', ....})` instead of `type: 'POST'`

Comment: oh, I tried that. And error is disappeared but, when I do filter. Not, filtering but console is getting all html :) this is so painful....

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help :). Just curious, did you solve the problem by rewriting the backend service?

Comment: actually, it was my backend problem. I gave new routing for the data and change the Ajax endpoint to that path. :) but your code fixed a lot...

Comment: I think I need more help from you, about vue. I am trying to rebuilt filter system in vue. if you have a time for help me out. Really appreciate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415053/making-filters-with-laravel-vue

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.
This is often done on the server, but if your data set is small enough it can work. If you set the filterable data points as data elements of your items you can just compare the selected value from the filter. jQuery's `each` function is one way to loop through the elements and you can then use the `data` function to access the appropriate data attribute.

```js
$('#room-filter').on('change', function() {
  const numRooms = $(this).val();
  $('.card').each(function() {
    if (numRooms && numRooms != $(this).data('rooms')) {
      $(this).slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Rooms:
<select id="room-filter">
  <option value="">Show All</option>
  <option value="1">1 Room</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rooms</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rooms</option>
</select>

<div class="card text-left" data-rooms="1">
  <div class="card-body d-flex" id="content-card">
    <h2>Shack</h2>
    <p class="main-text">1 room</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-left" data-rooms="1">
  <div class="card-body d-flex" id="content-card">
    <h2>Second Shack</h2>
    <p class="main-text">1 room</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card text-left" data-rooms="3">
  <div class="card-body d-flex" id="content-card">
    <h2>Bungalo</h2>
    <p class="main-text">3 rooms</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for answer. but i am trying to use ul li and give data-value. not options... is it possible to that way?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Can you put some code into the question or share a codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I update the question with the code and some explanation as well, could you please check it ou?